# Add block to category page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, layout, blocks, category

I want to add a custom block to the category pages and not care if the the category is anchor or not or if it has children or not.
I want to add that block at the bottom of the page after the product list or static block.
So I added this in the layout file

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="some/block" tempalate="some/template.phtml" after="-" /><!-- notice the "after" attribute -->
     </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

the block appears in every category page but at the top of the page.
If I change the layout handle to `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered` everything works OK and I see my block at the bottom of the page.
Any idea why "after" is ignored for `catalog_category_view` handle?
*Note:* Using the default magento theme

Comment: Seems like different order of block rendering. Some other children of `content` block of `catalog_category_view` is rendered after your block.

Comment: Good question by the way. Never head of `catalog_catagory_view` layout handle before.

Comment: Yep, but the question is why? I didn't see any `after="-"` on other blocks in all the category page layout handles. As for the layout handle name `catalog_category_view` is the default one generated for all the pages through `$this->addActionLayoutHandles();`

Comment: Yes I also heard `catalog_catagory_view` but I have done via code but via xml code. good questions.

Comment: Identify your last block load write as `after="lastblock"` it will might work

Comment: @KeyulShah. I don't want to do that, since the last block can be different in theory. I want my block "absolute last". I also know how to do that. I can create a custom handle and use `<update handle="my_handle" />` inside `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`. But I'm just curious to why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Marius when the second block is added it doesn't take into consideration what was set as `after` on the first block.

Comment: @Tim. If by block you  mean "layout handle" I think you might be on to something. If not, then I might be on to something :). I will post an answer shortly. (I hope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've isolated the problem.
The `catalog_category_view` layout handle is loaded before the `_layered` or `_default` handle and the block are generated in the order they are found. So my custom block is generated and inserted into the content before the `category/view` block found in the `_layered` handle.
So the 'after' attribute is taken into consideration and my block is added last at that point.
But then comes the `_layered` layout handle and because the `category/view` block does not have a before or after specified it is inserted like this:

```
$parentBlock->append($block, $alias);
```

That is the same thing as

```
$this->insert($block, '', true, $alias);
```

The same code is executed when `after="-"` is specified. So it's like `category/view` has `after="-"` specified.
This does not occur when the blocks are in the same layout handle, because usually the custom module layout handle is loaded after the one from `catalog.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

`before`: Used to position the block before a block with the **name specified** in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned before all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

`after`: Used to position the block after a block with the **name specified** in the value. If "-" value used the block is positioned after all other blocks of its level of block nesting.

Updated: examples from some random core layout updates:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**Updated:** I believe `before` and `after` work only in `core/text_list` and similar(descendant) blocks, i.e. blocks which just render blocks their nested blocks.

Comment: This will not work in some cases (obviously the case of a topic starter). This is a known problem of Magento 1.x and will be fixed in 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know what `before` and `after` should do and it should work for all the block types, not only `core/text_list`. Like I've said in the question, it works if I change the layout handle name.

Comment: ok Marius and Tim :)