# what is the difference between sorting blocks using after/before or sorting them in the xml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, frontend

I think the answer should be to preserve upgradability, so I can sort blocks using a local.xml file instead of modifying the original xml layout. But, what if I copy my own xml file, for example page.xml and I just sort blocks in the footer?

Example:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>
```

to:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
   <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
   <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Any other advantage?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to have understood the real power of using after/before instead of just sorting blocks in the layout files. Using the reference tag, I can insert a block by a local.xml or module layout file and tell to magento where to position it. For example, in a left or right structural block, I can insert a content block and tell to magento to put it after or before the poll module. Of course, it works for structural blocks that render automatically the content, like left, right or footer. I don't need to override any xml layout

Answer (score 2):

First I want to say that nothing ensures upgradability. It can only lower the risk.
But in this case I don't think that using the sort order with `before/after` is going to go away. If it does, we're all screwed.

The best practice says that you should copy and change as least as possible the original files and to use your own layout file or `local.xml` to do your changes. This way the risk of something blowing up after an upgrade is lower.

I can tell you from experience that once I upgraded an EE from 1.11 to 1.12 and something changed in the layout for the google analytics layout file, but previously I copied the layout file in my own theme. Lost about 4-5 hours until I figured it out.
So my advice is to use before/after sorting.

**[EDIT]**
I forgot something. In special cases the `before/after` sorting might not work. [See this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13513/146) for one of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

Block sorting using after/before is the same as sorting them in xml file, because layouts are all xml files. Did you mean sorting them in for example 'catalog.xml' instead of in 'local.xml'? If so, local.xml is meant for all updates because of upgrading and also because of keeping the code clean. If you have more themes, for example ProjectA and ProjectB, every one has its own local.xml file. So, if you would change base 'catalog.xml', changes will be shown for ProjectA and ProjectB, but if you use local.xml, changes can be different between themes.
Hope this is helpful.