# block is not rendered /custom block is not called at category page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i am try to create static block at category page,but its not called,

try this solutions:
clear cache,
allow block from admin,
disable magento cache from admin

from category setting selected 'static blocks with product'

```
/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/navigation/category.phtml

<?php
echo "hello";
```

/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
 <reference name="content">
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/navigation/category.phtml" />
```

Comment: adding only from `catalog.xml` won't work, you have to call block in template using `getChildBlock`

Comment: tysm for answer,but sir can u just explain me in more detail

Comment: do you want to show your block instead of product listing or want to append it ?

Comment: sir i just need to display sub category listing on parent category page,but  before that,static block is not called,thats why try to simple display echo hello first

Comment: you are using wrong alias for layout, you should use `catalog_category_default` or `catalog_category_layered` instead of `catalog_product_view`

Comment: you can also try `catalog_category_view`

Comment: also try that alies,still not rendered

Comment: Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13513/add-block-to-category-page)